# Mixing pure and impure with Cats Effect

Tags: scala, cats-effect

Suppose we have a two-stage pure method.

```
  def filterPositivePure(seq: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] =
    if (seq.nonEmpty) {
      val sorted = seq.sorted
      sorted.filter(_ > 0)
    }
    else seq
```

We needed to log the intermediate result of the calculations or any other impure action.

```
  def filterPositiveImpure(seq: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] =
    if (seq.nonEmpty) {
      val sorted = seq.sorted
      println(sorted)
      sorted.filter(_ > 0)
    }
    else seq
```

Then to preserve purity, we wrapped in IO the output to the log, the rest of the calculations and the result of the entire alternative if branch.

```
  def filterPositiveIO(seq: Seq[Int]): IO[Seq[Int]] =
    if (seq.nonEmpty) {
      val sorted = seq.sorted
      IO(println(sorted)) *> IO(sorted.filter(_ > 0))
    }
    else IO(seq)
```

Is there a more coincise way to bring purity back?

Answer (score 2):

I think better way is working on one action as a new effect and write separate function for logging:

```scala
import cats.syntax.all._

// now function looks more structural and without multiple using sorted list
def filterPositiveIO(seq: Seq[Int]): IO[Seq[Int]] = {
  if (seq.nonEmpty) 
    withLogging(seq.toList.sorted).map(_.filter(_ > 0))
  else
    IO(seq)
}

// this function is just for making some logging effect and return lifted value into IO
def withLogging[A: Show](value: A): IO[A] = logging(value.show) >> IO(value)

// here you should make logging effect
def logging(strExpr: => String): IO[Unit] = ???
```

Comment: We wrapped in IO whole algo, pure and impure parts. May be it is more holistic approach.

Comment: What is the purpose of applying >> here def withLogging[A: Show](value: A): IO[A] = logging(value.show) >> IO(value) We got the original value by value why not *>